# I want to get Traffic information from google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Is there any way I can get traffic information at a particular point on map? If google doesnt have it, are Bing or Here traffic apis accurate?

Comment: there is a `TrafficLayer` available for google maps

Answer (score 0):

As per comment - there is a traffic layer available - an example below of how to apply it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Using a Traffic layer in Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        width:800px;
        height:600px;
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: {lat:51.521473, lng:-0.134587 }
        });

        var traffic = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        traffic.setMap( map );
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```